# How to change hidden input price with oninput event

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

This is my code
**Here is hidden price came from last page**

```
<input disabled="disabled" type="text" class="field" style="text-align:center;" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['TotalPrice'])){$price =mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['TotalPrice']); echo $price; } ?>" />
```

**On this page i add a input type of coupon code**

```
<input type="text" size = "3" name="couponadd" id="couponadd" oninput="myFunction()" class="field" placeholder="Enter Coupon Code" />
```

**oninput set a function and getting a values**

```
<script>
 function myFunction() {
   var getcoupon = $("#couponadd").val(),
      txt='Invaild Coupon';
   if (getcoupon == 'gold') {
     alert('Minus 15%');

   } else if (getcoupon == 'silver') {
     alert('Minus 10%');

   }
      **Here I want if coupon code matched do 10% or 15% from the total price on the above**
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are more than one mistakes with your code.

You should not set the field as `disabled`.It should be `type="hidden"`
Then I have attached one `id` with it and got its value. And after checking the discount value, I have again assigned the updated value to the hidden field.

```
<input type="hidden" id="total_price" class="field" style="text-align:center;" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['TotalPrice'])){$price =mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['TotalPrice']); echo $price; } ?>" />

<script>
 function myFunction() {
   var getcoupon = $("#couponadd").val();
   var total_price = $('#total_price').val();
      txt='Invaild Coupon';
   if (getcoupon == 'gold') {
     alert('Minus 15%');
     total_price = total_price - (total_price * 0.15);

   } else if (getcoupon == 'silver') {
     alert('Minus 10%');
     total_price = total_price - (total_price * 0.10);

   }
   $('#total_price').val(total_price);  // Here I am updating discounted value in the hidden field.
 }
</script>
```

Comment: If total price is 100 and you get 10% discount - your logic will return total price = 10, but it should be 90

Comment: Opps, thank you for pointing out @NafiulIslam. i am updating my answer. Please remove down vote.

Comment: @rahul, I think this will help you. Have you checked this ?

Comment: Sir is that possible after minus 15 or 10% from total price should not be like in point like 120.5 or 156.6 etc..it should be 120 or 156

Comment: @rahul, can you accept this answer as it gives answer what you had asked in your main question?
And to make the discounted price an integer value, would you like to round off the value or you just want to remove decimal portion.?

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay sir .just decimal points if the value up to .6 then it should be show next number. like if  125.6 then show 126 and if 125.5 they 125

Comment: @rahul, you can do that like this `total_price = Math.round(total_price);`
I hope this will help you out.

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay sir .if somebody use coupon code twice in same time  how to stop that  ..in this code we did' t use any check if any coupon code entered twice in one time..

Comment: You can not do that only with jquery. You have to use mysql too. You have to store all coupons with user id, to store that a user with id 7 has used this code and then you should not allow the same user to use the coupon. You have to execute a mysql query to confirm that.

Answer (score 0):

You have to take input of hidden value using jquery specific field:

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {
      var getcoupon = $("#couponadd").val(),
        txt='Invaild Coupon',
        price = $('input.field:disabled).val(), //Get value from hidden input
        discount = getcoupon == 'gold' ? .15 : getcoupon === 'silver' ? .1 : 0;

      price = price * (1 - discount); // calculate price after discount
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You're using a disabled field btw, not a hidden one. Try to name it with a proper class or id so that accessing is easier

Answer (score 0):

Try the fowling code :

```js
 onload = function (){
  var e = document.getElementById('couponadd');
       e.oninput = function (){
       
     var getcoupon = $("#couponadd").val(),
      txt='Invaild Coupon';
   if (getcoupon == 'gold') {
     console.log('Minus 15%');

   }  if (getcoupon == 'silver') {
     console.log('Minus 10%');
 }
       e.onpropertychange = e.oninput; // for IE8
       e.onchange = e.oninput;
   }
      };
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" size = "3" name="couponadd" id="couponadd"  class="field" placeholder="Enter Coupon Code" />
```